# handling arrays in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table and I need to display values in table from my JSON response. But I am unable to fetch the datas inside array.somewhere I am missing something.

JSON:

```
var jobs = [
    {"id":1,"title":"Need comedian","company":"AMS","description":"Need comedian"},        
    {"id":2,"title":"Need Actor","company":"ERS","description":"Actor for Romantic Movie"}
]
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat ="item in jobs">
    <td>{{item.jobs.title}}</td>
    <td>{{item.jobs.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If that `jobs` is the one you are exposing to the `ng-repeat` you just need `{{ item.title }}` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use $scope:

```
$scope.jobs = [{"id":1,"title":"Need comedian","company":"AMS","description":"Need comedian"},{"id":2,"title":"Need Actor","company":"ERS","description":"Actor for Romantic Movie"}]

<tr ng-repeat ="item in jobs">
    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: oops yes its a really weird mistake I did. thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues,

(i)You need to use **`$scope`** variable

(ii)You need to access **`item.title`** not **`item.jobs.title`** inside **`ng-repeat`**

You should access item

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in jobs">
 <td>{{item.title}}</td>
 <td>{{item.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ifN1tGhNRo0vpQtwn6mA?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

The jobs array needs to be in $scope.

```
$scope.jobs = [{"id":1,"title":"Need comedian","company":"AMS","description":"Need comedian"},{"id":2,"title":"Need Actor","company":"ERS","description":"Actor for Romantic Movie"}]

<tr ng-repeat ="item in jobs">
    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Keep these things in mind while playing with `ng-repeat` :**

- You have to use `$scope.jobs` object instead of `var jobs` as an array declaration in the controller which you are going to pass in `ng-repeat` for binding.
- When you are going to iterate the array inside `ng-repeat="item in jobs"` no need to use again `jobs` to access the property of the `objects(item) of an array(jobs)`.

**Working Demo :**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {
  $scope.jobs = [
    {
      "id":1,
      "title":"Need comedian",
      "company":"AMS",
      "description":"Need comedian"
    },        
    {
      "id":2,
      "title":"Need Actor",
      "company":"ERS",
      "description":"Actor for Romantic Movie"
    }
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat ="item in jobs">
            <td>{{item.title}}</td>
            <td>{{item.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```